# Conflict between partition switch/merge/split and CDC?

Tags: sql-server

We have an archiving process which uses partition switching on tables which are also tracked by CDC. Most of the time they work well together, but occasionally a partition operation - switch, merge or split - causes CDC to stop working.

The partition operation succeeds, but we start seeing error messages like:

> No catalog entry found for partition ID 72057594555072512 in database
>   8. The metadata is inconsistent. Run DBCC CHECKDB to check for a metadata corruption.

and the CDC capture job stops working. Running DBCC CHECKDB finds no errors. The only way we've been able to restart CDC is to drop and re-add the CDC configuration in the database.

Has anyone else ever come across this, and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late for this, but today the answer to this behavior is in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-enable-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> If you enable partition switching on SQL Server 2008 R2 through the current version, you might also need split and merge operations in near future. Before executing a split or merge operation on a replicated or CDC enabled table ensure that the partition in question does not have any pending replicated commands. You should also ensure that no DML operations are executed on the partition during the split and merge operations. If there are transactions which the log reader or CDC capture job has not processed, or if DML operations are performed on a partition of a replicated or CDC enabled table while a split or merge operation is executed (involving the same partition), it could lead to a processing error (error 608 - No catalog entry found for partition ID) with log reader agent or CDC capture job. In order to correct the error, it might require a reinitialization of the subscription or disabling CDC on that table or database.